# how to dynamically change chart attribute e.g. title?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

My real need is to change dimension attributes and xUnits attributes from a dropdown i.e. from months to weeks for a chart. I can do this statically by hardcoding the values:

```
dimT = data.dimension(function (d) {
   return d3.time.month/week(timeFormat.parse(d.invDt]));});
chart1 = dc.barChart(chrt_div)
    .dimension(dimT)
    .xUnits(d3.time.months/weeks)
```

From the drop.change I tried:

```
dimT = data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d3.time.week(timeFormat.parse(d.invDt));});
chart1.dimension(dimT);
chart1.xUnits(d3.time.weeks);
dc.renderAll(); // just to be safe
```

and it does not work. Taking a step back I tried:

```
chart1.title("TitleChanged");
dc.renderAll(); //title does not change
```

Should I be able to make dynamic changes like this? All my references seem good.

Comment: If you're replacing the dimension you'll need to replace the group as well - data is pulled from the group and only filtering happens on the dimension. Also you'll want to recycle or dispose your old dimensions since it will get slower with each new one created.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for following up.